# Why is one light staying on when the switch is off?

Tags: electrical

I have a lighting/wiring problem, I have two lights in a front room controlled by one dimmer switch, the problem is one stays on permanently and one switches on and off and dims.

The switch wire goes to the light that goes on and off, then the second light (the one staying on) is fed from that light by a single 3 core 1.5m cable.

The light staying on only has the one cable entering it, the other has 4 cables entering.

The configuration in the light staying on is one single earth (green/yellow), one single neutral (black) and one single live (red), each separated into the light fitting in separate terminals.

The configuration in the light switching off is currently all four live wires (red) bundled together into a separate terminal block (not connected to light fitting), three neutral wires (black) all bundled together going into the neutral of this light, all four earth wires (green/yellow) bundled together going into the earth of this light and one neutral wire (black with a red sleeve) going into the live of this light, something is obviously wrong but I can't figure out what it is, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hi did you manage to get it working? I am having the same problem and I am still stuck. How did you put it right?

Answer (score 2):

The red wire that goes to the second light (that is bundled with the rest of the reds at the first light), needs to be connected to the black with red sleeve wire. Since it's currently bundled with the rest of the red (hot) conductors, the light is always getting power. The black wire with a red sleeve is the switched hot lead, and only has power when the switch is on.

Comment: Thank you, which side of the terminal block into the same side as the switch wire or the oposite